# How to access a variable declared within browserify script

Tags: javascript, browserify

So I have this script 'source.js'.

```
var m = require("somemodule");
```

And then I built it with browserify:

```
$ browserify source -o build.js
```

Is there any way to access `m` within the chrome|firefox console?
Because of node.js encapsulation, `m` is not global...

Comment: Can you create a function in your script, and within the variable scope, that returns the value of the variable? If you want to debug it you could use console.log or just add breakpoints to view the value during execution.

Comment: I could do window.m , but managing n quantity of variables imagine how big would that be ! and yes, I can console.log from there, but that would having me refreshing every time...

Answer (score 4):

browserify wraps things in a closure, specifically to limit scope (like node.)

Use global (like node) or window to inject things into a shared scope. You can also require things again (like node)to get the cached scope (the same object.)

So, this is a trick to share a scope in node or browserify:

```
var m = require('m');
m.cool = true;

// in another file
var m = require('m');
console.log(m.cool);
```

To hoist it into global space, you can add `global.m = require('m')` in any script that is required in that browserify build-chain to add it to global namespace (which resolves to `window` in browserify.)

You can also use `browserify --standalone` on somemodule, if you want to expose it directly.

Comment: Jethik: It was the correct answer, but I added an edit for clarification.

Answer (score 3):

```
var m= require('m');

window.M= m;
```

after the browserify, `var moduleM = new M();`